# React Native iOS app setup without using default ./ios directory

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm integrating React Native into a pre-existing iOS application.  Since it's a long-standing git repo, I need to keep the directory structure intact.  So instead of having the iOS app files like `.xcworkspace` in `./ios`, I need to have them in the root of the repo `./`.  I have my React Native components in a directory called `./ReactComponents`, and I run:

```
(JS_DIR=`pwd`/ReactComponents; cd ReactComponents/node_modules/react-native; npm run start — — root $JS_DIR)
```

It seems to start the server fine, but when I then build from Xcode and navigate to the React Native screen, I get:

```
TransformError: {my_machine}/react-native/ios/ReactComponents/index.ios.js: Couldn't find preset "react-native" relative to directory "{my_machine}/react-native/ios"
```

What am I missing to ensure that npm knows where to look for the js files?

I'm using `React Native 0.45.1` btw

Thanks!

Comment: You can not change axioms, you have to put ios app inside the ios folder because react-native have distributed area for javascript, ios and android so that they don't collide each other.

Comment: There must be a way, right?  Integrating React Native into an existing project directory shouldn't require a complete restructure?

Comment: There might be a way to do this but it's not a good practice because in future you can face consequences and changing things in react-native node_module can impact in various areas, though i will try to do something..

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - it was a `babel` issue.  In `babel-preset-react-native`'s `package.json`, I had to change the default `/ios` to `/ReactComponents`.